# display of image name on hovering it.. with jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

this html code

```
<div id="imgDisp">
</div>
```

This jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imgSrc = "images/newIMG.png";

$("#imgDisp").css({
    background: "url("+imgSrc+") repeat"
});

var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = imgSrc; 

newImg.onload = function() {
    var imgHeight = newImg.height;
    var imgWidth = newImg.width;

    $("#imgDisp").css({
        width : imgWidth*10,
        height: imgHeight*10
    });
}
});
```

Through this code I repeated an image 10 times horizontally and 10 times vertically. i.e. a 10x10 box i got.

Now i tried something so that when i hover on image the name of image shall come..
But image name shall be the number at which it is present. i.e. n hovering image at 2nd row 3rd column its name shall be displayed as i=2, j=3.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Do you just want each image to have a unique, incremented name?

Comment: I get the feeling this question is out of context. For a start, the selector is selecting an element with an ID, not a class, therefore; only one result will ever be found.

Comment: @MickMalone1983. yes.. I want image name incremented but in both dimensions.. as 10 images is shown horizontally and 10 vertically.. so first image name as 1, 1, 2nd image in same row 1, 2 and so on

Comment: @seer the id is used because the repetition of so many images was hanging the browser..

Comment: @Swati You should be using a class, not an ID. You can't use the same ID twice on any element in the same page.

Comment: @Swati Ahaa, I see what you're trying to do here now... interesting approach...

Comment: @seer My target was to repeat the images many times.. both horizontally and vertically..
Using php hanged the browser and page was very slow.. This fixed it..

Comment: just give a "title="click here to go to somewhere.com"" attribute to the <img> tag , it will display it on image hover

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid It's not an image, that's the thing. If he wants to do this, using img tags would be best approach, but either way he'll need multiple elements or some weird way of updating the title depending on the position of the cursor in the container... lol

Comment: @Seer : its a 'SHE' by the way , well thanx , yeah i know that , i just wanted to give an alternative to append the image with a title attribute

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Well, I wasn't to know. I didn't mean any offense. ^^

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid thanx for ur possible solution.. but could it be a valid one?

Comment: @Swati : try and see for your self , but yes , its a valid one , worked for me atleast

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location of the mouse on `mousemove` with the event `pageX`/`pageY` members (ordinarily you will have to subtract the offset as well, but in my example everything is flush top-left):

```
$("#imgDisp").css({
        width : imgWidth*10,
        height: imgHeight*10
    }).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var i = Math.ceil(e.pageX / imgWidth);
        var j = Math.ceil(e.pageY / imgHeight);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgbed/2/

Comment: what you show is right.. But my target is to get these values on the mouse location.. not somewhere fixed..

Comment: @Swati subtract the offset from the pageX (`var i = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;`)

Comment: i think you dont understand what i want to say.. 
My target was to get the location where the pointer of mouse is.. not at some fixed place as you had made. :(
Like you take mouse over an image and a tooltip shows a message..
That sort of message for the location

Comment: @Swati That's not hard to do; instead of the span just append an element with fixed position at `e.pageX`/`e.pageY` plus a little bit

Comment: @Swati I've already done a lot of work with you for no reward .. why do you think I'm going to write code for you for free?

Comment: u got reward.. i awarded ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Add all id images like that `var images = $("#img1, #img2, #img3,.... #img10");`
and then on hover use `$(this).attr('id');`